# Getting "The app doesn't support Safe App functionality"

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-apps-sdk, safe

My app already [exist](https://app.mesha.club/login), built using Next.js and I want to add Safe App functionality to it in order to list on Safe web interface. Referred the [docs](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/learn/safe-apps/get-started) and added both `manifest.json` and `config-overrides.js` files with following contents respectively as per the docs:

```js
{
  "name": "Mesha",
  "description": "Financial stack for Web3 teams",
  "iconPath": "public/images/mesh_icon.svg",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
}
```

```js
/* config-overrides.js */

module.exports = {
    // The function to use to create a webpack dev server configuration when running the development
    // server with 'npm run start' or 'yarn start'.
    // Example: set the dev server to use a specific certificate in https.
    devServer: function (configFunction) {
        // Return the replacement function for create-react-app to use to generate the Webpack
        // Development Server config. "configFunction" is the function that would normally have
        // been used to generate the Webpack Development server config - you can use it to create
        // a starting configuration to then modify instead of having to create a config from scratch.
        return function (proxy, allowedHost) {
            // Create the default config by calling configFunction with the proxy/allowedHost parameters
            const config = configFunction(proxy, allowedHost);

            config.headers = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization',
            };

            // Return your customised Webpack Development Server config.
            return config;
        };
    },
    webpack: (config, _env) => {
        return config;
    },
};
```

Then started my app locally using `yarn dev` command. Here `dev` inside `package.json` file under `scripts` property defined like this `"dev": "next dev"`. App started on `http://localhost:3000`. Then I used Ngrok with command `ngrok http 3000` to give my app a public url like this `https://b630-2406-16c0-101-957-48ef-57a4-f240-c4f6.in.ngrok.io`.

Now when I use ngrok url in the Safe's `Add custom app` input then getting following message in the screenshot. I also tried and referred other safe app repos mentioned [here](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/learn/safe-apps#existing-safe-apps) and also installed [Safe Apps Provider SDK](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/master/packages/safe-apps-provider) but no luck. I am currently struggling to make it working and move forward. Any guidance or help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Such an error will generally be shown if the manifest.json is malformed or can't be fetched. In your case, it seems valid, so I guess it cannot be fetched. For the exact error message, you should check the console/networks tab in your browser.

Comment: Checked, so I am getting CORS error. `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: MissingAllowOriginHeader`. I even shifted the `manifest.json` in `public` folder but it is still showing CORS error but working when i simply try the url in browser. Browser shows data in `manifest.json` file.

Comment: Then it would be best if you looked up how to properly set up CORS on the server you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after getting idea from [mikheevm's comment](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145491/getting-the-app-doesnt-support-safe-app-functionality?noredirect=1#comment167659_145491). It is like, steps mentioned in the Safe [docs](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/learn/safe-apps/get-started) are not applicable for Next.js based apps as they have a dedicated file `next.config.js` to make it working. So, I did below things.

1. Added `manifest.json` file in `/public` folder with following content:

```js
{
  "name": "<app name>",
  "description": "<app description>",
  "iconPath": "<path to app logo>"
}
```

2. Referred [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/security-headers) and added headers in the `headers` array like this:

```js
[
  {
    key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    value: '*',
  },
  {
    key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    value: 'GET',
  },
  {
    key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    value: 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization',
  },
]
```

3. Updated [Content security policy's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) `frame-ancestors` to enable safe url like this:

```js
'self' https://app.safe.global;
```

I think Safe guys should consider updating documentation as this might be confusing for someone who is not familiar with these things.

Hope this will help others.